# Open a new tab in background on chrome, firefox and ie

Tags: python, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, background

I wonder how do I call python in a new tab in the main browsers chrome, firefox and ie, but have to open that tab in the background. The same should not open the face of my user, but in the background.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Open a new tab in browser using python. But on open a new tab, the new tab should not open the front should open in background.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661142/controlling-a-browser-using-python-on-a-mac-firefox-or-safari-or-chrome-ium-or
They recommend http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ or https://code.google.com/p/spynner/

Comment: @debianplebian thanks for links. Wow! Never thought that its possible!

Comment: @akaRem sadly, python cannot do the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: @debianplebian In my view it is not duplicated. Could illustrate the links do not quite understand.

Comment: @debianplebian How does that correspond to my comment?

Comment: @akaRem I mean to say that everything besides the halting problem was possible in python. Though about it, but didn't write it.

Comment: This isn't possible in a general manner because each browser behaves very differently when it comes to tab handling. To achieve this, you need to use a framework that has per-browser code that implements this feature.

Comment: no have problem in implements a function foreach browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mozmill for firefox, like so:

```
controller.rootElement.keypress('t', {'ctrlKey':true});
```

here are the [documents for Mozmill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozmill).

Comment: Yes, as long as the firefox has the browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground set to true

Comment: In that case, how can I set this to true this parameter via python?

Comment: Okay, I'll search it sink. Thank you. Can you tell me how to make Google Chrome?